# Is there a bound on the number of connected components of a zero set of an integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, differential-equations, differential-algebra

If $f$ is a real-analytic function on $[0,1]^n$, and $f$ has finite differential transcendence degree, is there some way to bound the number of connected components of its zero set or the set where it is positive in terms of $n$, the differential transcendence degree of $f$, the degree of polynomials in a characteristic set for $f$, and the sizes of the coefficients in the polynomials in the characteristic set? I am thinking of the example $f(x)=\cos(\alpha )$ for some real $\alpha$, where one always has $″=−\alpha^2$ but, as $\alpha$ becomes large, the number of connected components goes to infinity in a polynomial way in terms of $\alpha$.

There is a result like this for Pfaffian functions, where the number of connected components can be bounded by the Pfaffian format and degree of $f$ -- proved [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(99)00017-1) by Zell -- but I do not know of any result that works in this more general setting.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can eliminate $\alpha$ by one more differentiation, and obtain that $f=\cos\alpha x$ satisfies
$$f'''f-f''f'=0,$$
so the number of components of the zero set cannot be estimated in terms of quantities that you listed.